# Why does the mean output of multivariate_normal method differ from the mean of distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12)
num_observations = 5
x1 = np.random.multivariate_normal([1, 1], [[1, .75],[.75, 1]], num_observations)

sum = 0
for i in x1:
    sum += i  

print(sum/num_observations)
```

In this snippet the output is coming as [ 0.95766788  0.79287083] but shouldn't it be [1,1] as while generating the multivariate distribution I have taken the mean as 1,1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `multivariate_normal` does is:

> Draw random samples from a multivariate normal distribution.

With the key word here being **draw**.  You are basically taking a fairly small **sample** that is not guaranteed to have the same mean as the distribution itself.  (That's the mathematical expectation, nothing more, and your sample size is 5.)

```
x1.mean(axis=0)
# array([ 0.958,  0.793])
```

Consider testing this by taking a much larger sample, where the law of large numbers dictates that your means should more reliably approach 1.00000...

```
x2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([1, 1], [[1, .75],[.75, 1]], 10000)
x2.mean(axis=0)
# array([ 1.001,  1.009])
```

In other words: say you had a population of 300 million people where the average age was 50.  If you randomly picked 5 of them, you would *expect* your mean of the 5 to be 50, but it probably wouldn't be exactly 50, and might even be significantly far off from 50.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brad, exactly the answer I needed. I was under the impression that it would generate 5 samples and return that but it just draws 5 values from the distribution.